# c++, Linear interpolation between unsigned chars

Tags: c++, casting

Unexpectedly for me I faced strange issue:

Here is example of LOGICAL implementation of trivial linear Lagrange interpolation :

```
unsigned char mix(unsigned char x0, unsigned char x1, float position){
    // LOGICALLY must be something like (real implementation should be 
    // with casts)...
    return x0 + (x1 - x0) * position;
}
```

Arguments `x0`, `x1` are always in range 0 - 255.
Argument position is always in range `0.0f - 1.0f`.

Really I tried huge amount of implementations (with different casts and etc.) but it doesn't work in my case! It returns incorrect results (looks like variable overflow or something similar. After looking for solution in internet for a whole week i decided to ask. May be someone has faced similar issues.

I'm using MSVC 2017 compiler (most of parameters are default except language level).
OS - Windows 10x64, Little Endian.

What do i do wrong and what is possible source of the issue?

UPDATED:
It looks like this issue is more deep than I expected (thanks for your responses).

Here is the link to tiny github project which demonstrates my issue:
https://github.com/elRadiance/altitudeMapVisualiser

Output bmp-file should contain smooth altitude map. Instead of it, it contains garbage. If I use just x0 or x1 as result of interpolation function (without interpolation) it works. Without it - doesn't (produces garbage).

**Desired result (as here, but in interpolated colors, smooth)**
[image: Desired result (as here, but in interpolated colors, smooth)]

**Actual result (updated, best result achieved)**
[image: Actual result (updated, best result achieved)]

Main class to run it:

```
#include "Visualiser.h"


int main() {

unsigned int width = 512;
unsigned int height = 512;


float* altitudes = new float[width * height];

float c;

for (int w = 0; w < width; w++) {
    c = (2.0f * w / width) - 1.0f;
    for (int h = 0; h < height; h++) {
        altitudes[w*height + h] = c;
    }
}

Visualiser::visualiseAltitudeMap("gggggggggg.bmp", width, height, altitudes);

delete(altitudes);
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please give an example of inputs and unexpected output.

Comment: This sub statement `x1 - x0` if `x1` is smaller than `x0` (ie if signed then the result would be negative) you will get wraparound.  You need to take care when subtracting unsigned value that you get the result you expect.

Comment: [Works for me.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64dd296e60d06e1c) I doubt this is a problem with the code (or the language, for that matter). Could you add what you are expecting and what you are actually getting?

Comment: What do you mean by incorrect value? If you just do std::cout of the result, you will get the ASCII character corresponding to the result - this may be what you mean by overflow. Try casting the result before displaying it i.e. std::cout << static_cast<unsigned __int32>(result)<<std::endl.

Comment: @RichardCritten That's not a problem in this case. In fact, the unsigned wraparound behavior is what we would want from this piece of code. `mix(100, 0, 0.2)` will correctly output 80.

Comment: Updated my question. Thank you for your answers (codebase and examples of output added)

Comment: I second @aschepler GIve a range of input and tell us what it should be, there could be a variety of reasons why your bmp looks wrong.

Comment: Break your assignment across a couple of variables and debug each step instead of using a compound statement where things can get muddled.  From there, you can see exactly at what step the values go awry.

Comment: @MooingDuck Well that's weird, because [I do get 224](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8911125d19000326).

Comment: @Nelxiost: I totally forgot about integer promotion quirks. You're right.

Comment: That makes me question: @Radiance, what do you mean by "(real implementation should be with casts)"? If you are casting something (like `(x1 - x0)`, or `(x1 - x0)*position`) to `unsigned char` in the middle of the calculation, then of course you are going to get unexpected values.

Comment: @Nelxiost, probably  it will work without casts (explicit casts i mean). But I'm still not able to make it work properly, that is why I'm not sure

Comment: A bit improved actual result: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elRadiance/altitudeMapVisualiser/master/best_result_achieved.bmp

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Thankfully @wololo. Mistake in my project was not in calculations.

I should open file with option "binary":

```
file.open("test.bin", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::trunc | std::ios_base::binary);
```

Without it in some point in data can be faced byte with value `10` 
In Windows environment it can be processed like LineFeed and changed to `13`.